# Application ID error with GAE remote API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the Remote API in a local Client, following instructions given in Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi).

I first tried from the Remote API shell, and everything is working fine. I can connect to my remote datastore and fetch data.

But when I run the following script, which is very similar to Google's example :

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7
import sys

SDK_PATH = "/usr/local/google_appengine/"
sys.path.append(SDK_PATH)
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
import model.account

def auth_func():
  return ('myaccount', 'mypasswd')

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi('myappid', '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func)

# Fetch some data
entries = model.account.list()
for a in entries:
    print a.name
```

then I get an error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./remote_script_test.py", line 26, in <module>
      entries = model.account.list()
    [...]
    File "/Developer/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1333, in check_rpc_success
      raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_'
```

It says my application ID is a plain underscore '_', which is not the case since my app.yaml is correctly configured and when I do a

```
print app_identity.get_application_id()
```

from that script I get the correct application ID. I am under the impression that the GAE environment is not properly setup, but I could not figure out how to make it work. Does anyone have a full piece of code that works in this context ?

I am using Mac Os X Mountain Lion.

Comment: What do you have in your model.account?

Comment: model.account defines a simple model class, using the NDB API. The list() method makes a query to fetch all entries in the database. Nothing specific about that, the model is working fine in the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to start with remote_api_shell.py and remove stuff until it breaks, rather than add in things until it works.

For instance there's a line after the one you copied: `remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()` is that necessary?  There may be a number of necessary lines in remote_api_shell.py, maybe better to customize that rather than start from scratch.

Comment: Well, that was a good suggestion ! Actually, playing with remote_api_shell.py it appeared that all I had to do is move the import statement for my model module after the remote_api_stub initialization : `remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi('myappid', '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func)`, then `import model.account`. I don't quite understand why, but it works !

Comment: Glad to hear it!  That makes some sort of sense, I suppose.  remote_api may need to override some datastore rpc functions before ndb is imported for instance.